# Batch file increment folder number

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that creates folders 1.2.0.1, 1.2.0.2,1.2.0.3, etc.
I fould this code from a previous question and it almost works for my needs:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "baseName=New_Folder"
set "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "%baseName%[0-9]*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
 set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
 if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
md "%baseName%%n%"
```

so the way I attempted it is to have two variables, one holds the first three digits 2.4.0 and the other holds the forth one.

```
set version=1.2.0
cd C:\Users\Build
set "lastFolder=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%version%*."^|findstr /xri "%version%[0-9]*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%version%=!"
  if !name! gtr !lastFolder! set "lastFolder=!name!"
)
set /a nextFolder=lastFolder+1
md "%version%.%nextFolder%"
```

but this doesn't work because it's only creating the first folder and not the ones following. Can anyone help me determine the issue? Thanks

Comment: its something to do when calling md with the period in between the two variables 'version' and 'nextFolder' if I remove the period it works fine, but not to the format I want. any explanations?

Answer (score 1):

This will create folders, if they exist or not.

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,255) do MD "1.2.0.%%a" 2>nul
```

This should create only the next folder in the series:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\Build
for /L %%a in (1,1,20000000) do if not exist "1.2.0.%%a\" MD "1.2.0.%%a" & goto :done
:done
```

This is your code that now works - and it does exactly the same as the code above, within reason.  2 million folders seems to be a fair number, even if it takes a few seconds. :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set version=1.2.0.
cd C:\Users\Build
set "lastFolder=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%version%*."^|findstr /xri "%version%[0-9]*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%version%=!"
  if !name! gtr !lastFolder! set "lastFolder=!name!"
)
set /a nextFolder=lastFolder+1
md "%version%%nextFolder%"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to stick to my original solution if possible. Can you point me to exactly where the error is in my implementation?

Comment: Isn't a simpler solution better than a complex one?  If you didn't describe your task properly then start another question.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `!` and `.` is not being correctly handled:

```
...
'2^>nul dir /b /ad "%version%.*"^|findstr /xri "%version%.[0-9]*"'
...
set "name=!name:*%version%.=!"
...
set /a nextFolder=!lastFolder!+1
...
```